# How I need to create a Jqgrid If I mutliple JSON object in different column?

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I need to create a Jqgrid with this value given bellow. I need to create a column empId, empName, dailyLogDate, dayIn, timeIn, dayOut, timeOut, hours,
    authorized, authorizedBy, status, remarks": ..., In this value I can get the value for empId, empName, But I cannot get the values inside dailyattandence.
    How I need Create the Jqgrid columns by this available Json data. Dailyattandence may have more json data. So it should be in array list or like loop.

```
[
{
    "_id": "57189cc9f9d048e5cc2385d3",
    "empId": 2607,
    "empName": "Kumaran Gnanasekaran",
    "dailyAttendence": [
        {
            "dailyLogDate": "2016-04-17T00:00:00.000Z",
            "dayIn": "16/04/1016",
            "timeIn": "11:36",
            "dayOut": "16/04/2016",
            "timeOut": "20:26",
            "hours": "8:50",
            "authorized": "no",
            "authorizedBy": "",
            "status": "",
            "reason": {
                "remarks": "",
                "reasonForLate": "",
                "reasonForLeavingEarly": ""
            },
            "isPresent": "yes"
        },
        {
            "dailyLogDate": "2016-04-17T00:00:00.000Z",
            "dayIn": "",
            "timeIn": "",
            "dayOut": "",
            "timeOut": "",
            "hours": "",
            "authorized": "no",
            "authorizedBy": "",
            "status": "",
            "reason": {
                "remarks": "",
                "reasonForLate": "",
                "reasonForLeavingEarly": ""
            },
            "isPresent": "no"
        },
        {
            "dailyLogDate": "2016-04-18T00:00:00.000Z",
            "dayIn": "18/04/1016",
            "timeIn": "10:36",
            "dayOut": "18/04/2016",
            "timeOut": "20:16",
            "hours": "9:40",
            "authorized": "no",
            "authorizedBy": "",
            "status": "",
            "reason": {
                "remarks": "",
                "reasonForLate": "",
                "reasonForLeavingEarly": ""
            },
            "isPresent": "yes"
        },
        {
            "dailyLogDate": "2016-04-19T00:00:00.000Z",
            "dayIn": "",
            "timeIn": "",
            "dayOut": "",
            "timeOut": "",
            "hours": "",
            "authorized": "no",
            "authorizedBy": "",
            "status": "",
            "reason": {
                "remarks": "",
                "reasonForLate": "",
                "reasonForLeavingEarly": ""
            },
            "isPresent": "no"
        },
        {
            "dailyLogDate": "2016-04-20T00:00:00.000Z",
            "dayIn": "20/04/1016",
            "timeIn": "10:36",
            "dayOut": "20/04/2016",
            "timeOut": "20:20",
            "hours": "9:44",
            "authorized": "no",
            "authorizedBy": "",
            "status": "",
            "reason": {
                "remarks": "",
                "reasonForLate": "",
                "reasonForLeavingEarly": ""
            },
            "isPresent": "yes"
        },
        {
            "dailyLogDate": "2016-04-21T00:00:00.000Z",
            "dayIn": "21/04/1016",
            "timeIn": "12:00",
            "dayOut": "21/04/2016",
            "timeOut": "20:16",
            "hours": "8:16",
            "authorized": "no",
            "authorizedBy": "",
            "status": "",
            "reason": {
                "remarks": "",
                "reasonForLate": "",
                "reasonForLeavingEarly": ""
            },
            "isPresent": "yes"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: You can have *different* values `dailyLogDate, dayIn, timeIn, ...` for different items of `dailyAttendence`. What and how you want to display the data in the grid? You can for example display subgrid with the data or to duplicate the same `empId, "empName"` values in multiple rows or ... There are many ways and everything is possible to implement in jqGrid, but one should decide what one needs to have.

Comment: Just give me a rough code to show this columns in Jqgrid.

Comment: The code is absolutely different in case of usage subgrid or duplication the same `empId`, `empName` values. The code could be very different depend on the usage of different version of jqGrid and different forks of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop, commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Moreover it's important to know, which `datatype` you use (`"loca"` or `"json"`): the code will be a little different too. In general the main idea is the usage of callback functions to process response

Comment: I am using "json" datatype.